# Translating English to logical predicate

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, first-order-logic, quantifiers

What is the translation of this sentence to logical predicate "A student in your class has taken a course in logic programming"?

Comment: Could you please provide domain, and all premises in advance so that we could come up with predicate logic formula using existential quantifier.

Comment: What have *you* come up with so far? What are you struggling with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider $U$ to be the collection of all the students in the class that you mentioned, and let $P(x)$ be the expression $P(x) = \text{ “Student $x$ has taken a course in logic programming.”}$ Then your statement is of the form

$$(\exists x \in U):[P(x)].$$

If the domain is to be all people in the world (say $W$) then you have to define a expression $S(x)$ to be $S(x) = \text{ “Person $x$ is a student in your class.”}$ Then your statement is of the form

$$(\exists x \in W):[S(x) \wedge P(x)].$$

(Since the statement can be rephrased as “There is a person that is in your class and has taken a course in logic programming”.)